How to import supabase into service worker?
I want to import supabase into service worker so the content script can request the service worker to save data sent from it to the database.
I have tried multiple approaches but to no avail and below is one of the errors I have encountered.
manifest.json
{
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "serviceWorker.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}

serviceWorker.js
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

// these values are hard coded
const supabaseUrl = SUPABASE_URL; 
const supabaseAnonKey = SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;

const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey);

console.log(supabase)

Output
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@supabase/supabase-js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".



You need to use a bundler like webpack or rollup. Another solution is to manually download a compiled js from CDN into your extension directory. 2) supabase doesn't work inside a service worker, you'll need to use it in the offscreen document.

